# Should I backup the ".npm" and ".node-gyp" folder?

Tags: node.js, backup, npm, node-gyp

I am working on a backup plan for my hard-drive, and I would like to know whether there is any need to backup the hidden folders "~/.npm" and "~/.node-gyp"? Or they are just temporary folders whose content is built automatically?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `~/.npm` folder is a cache folder that contains local packages so that you don't have to download them over and over when you install them in a new project. You can safely delete this folder and you can in fact do it using the [`npm cache` command](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-cache.html):

```
$ npm cache clean
```

The `~/.node-gyp` folder is the `devDir` of `node-gyp` (see [relevant source code](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/blob/master/lib/node-gyp.js#L59)). [This is where development header files are copied](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/blob/master/lib/install.js#L4) in order to perform the compilation of native modules. you can safely delete this directory, as it will be re-created the next time you'll install a module that needs `node-gyp`.

Comment: There are also `/tmp/npm-*` directories that can occupy a lot of space. They can be also safely deleted. Usually this is something that is performed by an OS automatically, but sometimes you may want to remove them manually, e.g. when building Docker image.

Comment: Deleting `~/.npm` makes sense when you want to remove the cache and make free space. But when you are formatting/rebuilding a machine, does it not make more sense to backup this folder instead so you don't have to download a ton of packages again? If you backup this folder and paste it in the home directory (`~/`) of the new installation, will it work?